# Two dimensional array slice in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm looking to slice a two dimensional array in C#.

I have double[2,2] prices and want to retrieve the second row of this array. I've tried prices[1,], but I have a feeling it might be something else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange but it still not possible for C# 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges .

And works perfectly for F# 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/slices

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no direct "slice" operation, but you can define an extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SliceRow<T>(this T[,] array, int row)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        yield return array[i, row];
    }
}

double[,] prices = ...;

double[] secondRow = prices.SliceRow(1).ToArray();
```

Comment: What does `this` do in `this T[,] array`?

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: It turns the static method into an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: Don't you misplace the `row` index here as I thought that it should be `array[row,column]` ?

Answer (score 6):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
                .Select(x => prices[1,x])
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is if you have a jagged or a multidimensional array... here's how to retrieve a value from either:

```
 int[,] rectArray = new int[3,3]
  {
      {0,1,2}
      {3,4,5}
      {6,7,8}
  };

 int i = rectArray[2,2]; // i will be 8

 int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][3]
  {
      {0,1,2}
      {3,4,5}
      {6,7,8}
  };

  int i = jaggedArray[2][2]; //i will be 8
```

EDIT: Added to address the slice part...

To get an int array from one of these arrays you would have to loop and retrieve the values you're after. For example:

```
  public IEnumerable<int> GetIntsFromArray(int[][] theArray) {
  for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
     yield return theArray[2][i]; // would return 6, 7 ,8  
  }
  }
```

Comment: OP wrote" "...want to retrieve the second row..."  In your example, I think OP wants jaggedArray[2] or an int[3] that contains {6,7,8}

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core 2.1 and later, you can use [`MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan<T>(T, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.createspan) method to create a linear span from a multidimensional array and then Slice the span to your liking.

```cs
double[,] table =
{
    { 12.345, 67.890 },
    { 23.456, 78.901 }
};

var tableSpan = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref table[0, 0], table.Length);
// tableSpan here is linear: [12.345, 67.890, 23.456, 78.901]

Span<double> slice = tableSpan.Slice(2, 2);
double[] oneDimension = slice.ToArray();
// slice and oneDimension here are both: [23.456, 78.901]
```