# What's the fastest way to convert a long list of int[16] to 16 long int[] in C#

Tags: c#, list, transpose

I have a long (10000+ entries) List of structs, each of which contain an int[16].  I want to transpose the data to create 16 int[] arrays which are 10000+ entries long.  Essentially, I want to transpose the data.  Is there any method faster than just iterating through the list and creating the new entries?

Comment: This link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801990/how-to-get-a-dimension-slice-from-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: If you can post the code you have already, people could suggest optimisations, otherwise from your description above it doesn't sound as though there would be a faster way.  The arrays would need to be created and the data copied, there's no way around doing the minimum that needs to happen.

Comment: Faster in what meaning ? Less code, higher performance ?

Comment: Is it possible that you don't need a physical copy of the arrays, just an easier way to access the `int` values with the indices the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

So you just want a array of the int[16]?

Maybe linq could do this

```
var newArray = fooArray.Select(foo => foo.IntVal).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do you:

```
struct Widget
{
  public int[] Values = new int[16]; 
}

public int[][] TransposeWidgets( List<Widget> widgets )
{
  int cols;
  int[][] result = new int[][];

  for ( int row = 0 ; i < 16 ; ++row )
  {
    results[row] = new int[ widgets.Count ];
    for ( int col = 0 ; col < widgets.Count ; ++col )
    {
      result[row][col] = widgets[col].Values[row];
    }
  }

}
```

Though it might be faster to iterate over the large list just once. If it's really large, iterating over that list could cause paging which would slow things down.