# c++ jagged array slice in c#

Tags: c#, c++

In c++ is possible to get a slice of multidimensional array, like

```
  double parallelopipedPts[8][3];
  parallelopipedPts[0];
  parallelopipedPts[1];
  ...
  parallelopipedPts[7];
```

In c# I am trying to emulate this and tried

```
  double[][] parallelopipedPts = new double[8][];
  parallelopipedPts[0];
  parallelopipedPts[1];
  ...
  parallelopipedPts[7];
```

However I am getting memory access issues

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you expand a bit? What element are you hoping to return? Or are you trying to return the address of the element?

Comment: I would like to get a slice (one dimension) of jagged array, How to do that in c#?

Comment: You can't. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4802062/1517578

Comment: On that question OP states he uses a Rectangular array, however if one uses a jagged array, would it be faster as stated in an answer from that question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your C# code, you've created an array of 8 'double arrays'.

The double arrays in that array-of-8 have not yet been assigned, so they are null.

You can populate it with arrays-of-3-doubles (for example) like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parallelopipedPts.Length; i++)
{
    parallelopipedPts[i] = new double[3];
}
```

Then you can safely use your sub-arrays.

Comment: Nope, double[][] parallelopipedPts = new double[8][3]; would not compile.

Comment: Is a for loop the only way out?

Comment: I guess to be fair I've never bothered trying to make an array like this in C#, since I'd rather build a specialized class with a bit more information attached.