# Get sub array from a 3D array

Tags: c#, arrays

If I have an array:

```
int[,,] mainArray = new int[10,10,3];
```

How can I get a sub array:

```
int[] sub = mainArray[0,1]; // Unfortunately this doesn't work
```

Where sub would contain the 3 elements

```
sub[0] = mainArray[0,1,0];
sub[1] = mainArray[0,1,1];
sub[2] = mainArray[0,1,2];
```

It would be easy to write a method to do this but is there a built in way to do it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1406083/3246555, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4801990

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use an extension method like this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int[] GetValues(this Array source, int x, int y)
    {
        var length = source.GetUpperBound(2);
        var values = new int[length+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length+1; i++)
        {
            values[i] = (int)source.GetValue(x, y, i);
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int[,,] mainArray = new int[10,10,3];
int[] sub = mainArray.GetValues(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use nested arrays instead.

```
// Initialization
int[][][] mainArray = new int[10][][];
for (int i = 0; i < mainArray.Length; i++)
{
    mainArray[i] = new int[10][];
    for (int j = 0; j < mainArray[i].Length; j++)
    {
        mainArray[i][j] = new int[3];
    }
}

// Usage
int[] sub = mainArray[0][1];
```

Yes, the initialization is a bit more complex, but other than that it's all the same. And nested arrays even have [better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/597729/146622) (but you shouldn't care about array performance unless your profiler told you so).

---

Here is a helper class I wrote to help with the initialization of nested arrays.

```
public static class NestedArray
{
    public static Array Create<T>(params int[] lengths)
    {
        Type arrayType = typeof(T);
        for (int i = 0; i < lengths.Length - 1; i++)
            arrayType = arrayType.MakeArrayType();

        return CreateArray(arrayType, lengths[0], lengths.Skip(1).ToArray());
    }

    private static Array CreateArray(Type elementType, int length, params int[] subLengths)
    {
        Array array = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, length);

        if (subLengths.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                Array nestedArray = CreateArray(elementType.GetElementType(), subLengths[0], subLengths.Skip(1).ToArray());
                array.SetValue(nestedArray, i);
            }
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int[][][] mainArray = (int[][][])NestedArray.Create<int>(10, 10, 3);
```

Full commented source code can be found [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/Virtlink/9063619).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Buffer.BlockCopy` and some math, if you always want the the last dimension:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(mainArray, (D2*i+j)*D3*sizeof(TYPE), sub, 0, D3*sizeof(TYPE));
```

will put `mainArray[i,j,]` in `sub`, where `D1`, `D2`, and `D3` are your dimensions and `TYPE` is the type of the array elements.