# unity C# line Renderer array of lines

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

i want to make many lines use line renderer and i need double array. One of them is number of lines, and other one is data of points position.

```
...
positions[n + 1] = new Vector3(positions[n].x + Bxpe, positions[n].y + Bype, positions[n].z + Bzpe);
linerenderer.SetPositions(positions);
...
```

it work when number of line is one but

```
...
positions[z,n + 1] = new Vector3(positions[n].x + Bxpe, positions[n].y + Bype, positions[n].z + Bzpe);
linerenderer[1].SetPositions(positions[???]);
...
```

when i want to make like this, i dont know how write it right way.

pleace help

Comment: Can you explain better what is your end goal?
Can you also share what steps you took to try to solve your problem.
please share a bit of code that can show the point where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep using a 2d-array checkout [how to "slice" arrays out of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406083/two-dimensional-array-slice-in-c-sharp)

However, in your case instead of a 2-dimensional array

```
Vector3[,]
```

I would rather simply use a jagged array

```
Vector3[][]
```

and then do e.g.

```
positions[z][n + 1] = positions[z][n] + new Vector3(Bxpe, Bype, Bzpe);
...
linerenderer[z].SetPositions(positions[z]);
```